# Inspect SignalR Message with Fiddler

Tags: signalr, fiddler

I am trying to use Fiddler to see the message format for a chat app using SignalR. But nothing is appearing in Fiddler when I send a message to the hub or receive one back. I am assuming I have to configure something in order to see these messages. Fiddler is picking up when I refresh the page and connect but nothing else appears. The purpose is so I can get the correct message format when using SignalR-Objc

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: an app running in chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Turn **Streaming** on in Fiddler.
2. If your SignalR transport is WebSockets requests may take a few seconds to come through while fiddler is on.

**Update:** See @J. Polfer's answer below on how to see Websocket messages in Fiddler.

Comment: I have clicked the button that says stream. Do I have to do anything else??

Comment: You should not have to, no.  Verify that you're binding at least 1 client side function to your hub BEFORE calling connection.start

Comment: Could it have something to do with using my web app to connect to the hub on a seperate host??

Comment: it absolutely could, you need to enable cross domain if you're doing that.  Aka in your startup you need to do Routes.RouteTable.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true })

Comment: You can see WebSockets in Fiddler; look on the discussion forum or the Fiddler blog.

Answer (score 6):

As of Fiddler 4.5, you can [view Websocket data natively](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-s-new-in-fiddler-4-5) in Fiddler.

Simply double-click on the connection (look for signalr/connect? HTTP requests), and click on the WebSocket tab in Fiddler.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for pointing that out - was tearing my hair out a little.

Answer (score 1):

It worked once I removed websockets from the transports. All the information showed up when I just used Longpolling.

Comment: How do you remove websockets from the transports?